# Do I have to restart rails to use a new generator?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, generator, webrick

I am trying to install a couple of gems shich include Rails generators. They were not installing properly until I restarted the WEBrick server. Is this common? Will I always have to restart the WEBrick server after installing new gems?

Comment: Yes..It is common..As after installing any new gem, you have to restart your server

Comment: The generators themselves should work fine. The functionality they generate may or may not require a restart.

Comment: @RORDeveloper You should add that in an answer, so I can upvote.

Comment: @DaveNewton You should add that in an answer, so I can upvote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After installing any new gem that affect the runtime app environment, you have to restart your server. After generation of a model or a controller or creation of a view you don't have to restart the server

Comment: This depends on what the gem does, not all gems affect runtime app behavior.